# aspnet vNext ActionFilter and TempData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create an ActionFilter in aspnet vNext. Within this filter I want to access to the TempData and the ViewData (both available in Controller in previous versions).I override the method
`public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)`

Into the `filterContext` I have the controller but is an [`object`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/64e726d2b26422c5452475627e4afaba307edec3/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions/ActionExecutingContext.cs) instead of [`ControllerBase`](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/39391d3a64d7#src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerContext.cs). I was expected a `ControllerBase` because in previous versions of MVC the `ControllerContext` (the base class of `ActionExecutingContext`) was a `ControllerBase`, [here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/39391d3a64d7#src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerContext.cs) is the source code in codeplex. I understand that this could be because the POCO controllers.

So, the question is, how can access to the TempData and the ViewData if the controller is an object. Simply doing a downcasting (something like this `(Controller)filterContext.Controller`) or there's a best way to do it.

**Update**

That I want to achieve if explain it in [this blog post](http://benfoster.io/blog/automatic-modelstate-validation-in-aspnet-mvc) but with aspnet 5.

Comment: Can you give more info as to what is the scenario that you are trying to achieve? `TempData` can be accessed through the `ITempDataDictionary` service from DI. Regarding `ViewData`, it probably depends on the scenario...if you are short-circuiting the request, then you can new up `ViewDataDictionary` yourself and set the `ViewData` property on a `ViewResult`, for example. Or if you want to just want to add data to the `ViewData` to which a controller's action adds more data, then I believe down casting is just fine.

Comment: I want to set data to later on the next request get it. As a concrete example I want to achieve the same as is explain it in [this blog post](http://benfoster.io/blog/automatic-modelstate-validation-in-aspnet-mvc). I'm going to add this information in the question.

Comment: @KiranChalla, I think that your comment is the anwser to my question. I'll use dependency injection. Could you please post as answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access **TempData** from within an action filter, you can get the service called `ITempDataDictionary` from DI.

To get this service from DI, you could either do something like `actionContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITempDataDictionary>()` from within your `OnActionExecuting` method. You could also use construction inject if you like by using **ServiceFilterAttribute**.

**NOTE:**
TempData by default depends on `Session` feature(i.e TempData's data is stored in Session) and so you need to few things to get it working.

- Reference `Microsoft.AspNet.Session` and `Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Memory` packages.
- In your `ConfigureServices` method, do the following:

  ```
  services.AddCaching();
  services.AddSession();
  ```
- In your `Configure` method, register the `Session` middleware (this is the one which creates/attaches a session to the incoming requests) and do it *before* registering MVC.

  ```
  app.UseSession();
  app.UseMvc(...)
  ```