# Using Using POST-REDIRECT-GET in ASP.NET MVC Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, custom-action-filter

In an **ASP.NET MVC Core** project how can I use an alternative of [this custom action filter class](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/the-post-redirect-get-pattern-in-asp-net-mvc/). When I copy the following in my project's controller folder it does not recognize the following objects `TempData[Key], ViewData` because it's using System.Web.Mvc namespace that is not used in ASp.NET MVC Core. I want to implement POST-REDIRECT-GET in my ASP.NET MVC Core project [as described here](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/the-post-redirect-get-pattern-in-asp-net-mvc/) but the author, it seems, is not using MVC Core:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;

namespace myASPCoreProject.Controllers
{

    public abstract class ModelStateTransfer : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        protected static readonly string Key = typeof(ModelStateTransfer).FullName;
    }

    public class ExportModelStateAttribute : ModelStateTransfer
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            //Only export when ModelState is not valid
            if (!filterContext.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Export if we are redirecting
                if ((filterContext.Result is RedirectResult) || (filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult))
                {
                    filterContext.Controller.TempData[Key] = filterContext.ModelState;
                }
            }

            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        }
    }

    public class ImportModelStateAttribute : ModelStateTransfer
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            ModelStateDictionary modelState = filterContext.Controller.TempData[Key] as ModelStateDictionary;

            if (modelState != null)
            {
                //Only Import if we are viewing
                if (filterContext.Result is ViewResult)
                {
                    filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.Merge(modelState);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Otherwise remove it.
                    filterContext.Controller.TempData.Remove(Key);
                }
            }

            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30448681/2030565) explains how to get it from the DI service.

Answer (score 3):

We can use Redirect To Action as you can read in the Microsoft's documentation  [RedirectToAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/preventing-open-redirects?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Configure DI:

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    // Add the temp data provider
    services.AddSingleton<ITempDataProvider, CookieTempDataProvider>();
}


[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(User user)
{
    _userRepository.Save(user);
    TempData["User"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = user.Id });
}
```

other example

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(User user)
{

      _userRepository.Save(user);
      return RedirectToAction(nameof(UserController.Index), "User");
    }
```